# Ruby: How to check class method is private inside test?

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-1.9.3

Inside rspec test, i have to check that my class method is private or public. How i can do this?

Comment: `Class.private_methods.include?(:my_method)` ?

Comment: Why would you want to test something like that? What is the use case?

Comment: @xlembouras Because someone may transfer method public to private and vice versa without checking if it can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
expect(MyClass.private_methods).to include :my_method
```